# HDMI for Android

Tags: hdmi

I would like to connect my GS4 to my plasma television. I have an HDMI adapter, but will the sound come from the television or my device? And what do I use other than the HDMI adapter?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: I want to test it before doing anything.

Comment: It won't harm your device -- the most that could happen is that you find out whether or not it's compatible with your television.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect your Android device to your plasma television with an [HDMI cable.](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/android-hdmi-cable) (Though I wouldn't suggest buying it from eBay.)[1](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/android-hdmi-cable) Sound should come from your television, I'll bet. Make sure the Android HDMI adapter is compatible with your device first.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to connect a Galaxy S4 to a TV is an MHL-to-HDMI adapter, [like this one that I use](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=108&cp_id=10833&cs_id=1083314&p_id=10020&seq=1&format=2).

[image: Galaxy S3/S4 MHL adapter]

You connect the micro-USB bit to the phone, the big USB end to a charger (the adapter needs power.  This will also allow your phone to charge while you're using it like this), and the HDMI to the TV.

Audio will come out of the TV, or whatever it sends the audio to normally.

If you select a different MHL adapter and it isn't specifically advertised as being for a Galaxy S3 or S4, you'll need an 11-to-5 pin adapter, like [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=108&cp_id=10833&cs_id=1083314&p_id=9716&seq=1&format=2), to use it with your phone, as Samsung uses a different connector for MHL than most other devices do.

Comment: That is actually very good advice, @user50798. If it's not a specified wire, the likelihood of it fitting most "any" Android device is high.